# Highly Customizable Graphing Software for Algorithmic Art

Tags: soft-question, math-software

For my local hacker/maker space I want to do some etched copper plates that have stylized algorithmic functions on them. If you've seen etched PCB circuits then you're familiar with what I'm talking about.

The graphing software I have, though, doesn't allow me to manipulate the line weight (for the individual functions) or image export properties enough to get the result I'm looking for.

What are some free or low cost graphing utilities that offer relatively customizable function aesthetics?

[image: An example of algorithmic art]

Comment: What kind of output do you need?

Comment: I'd like to be able to set the image size when I export it so that I wont lose line quality if I need to scale it up or down (you can see what I'm talking about in the example image). Either that or a vector format image.

Comment: You could write such drawings in PostScript, MetaPost, SVG, PyX or some other vector graphics language.

Comment: See http://pyx.sourceforge.net/examples/drawing2/insert.html for a PyX example of a similar spiral.

Comment: See also http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Op-art-4-sided-spiral-tunnel.svg and the PostScript code at the end.

Comment: Python is my jam so pyx looks great! Thanks